# Conditionally set environment variable in Apache config

Tags: linux, apache, environment-variables

I am trying to make a fall back for a Single Sign On module used by Apache. Normally when this module is enabled, after logging in once the module sets `HTTP_LOGIN` to the username. But I want to configure my webserver in such a way that I have a fall back option. My idea was to set an environment variable in the Apache config indicating which SSO solution is currently active. I checked this and it works as intended. The web application sees the new environment variable.

But I also want to force `HTTP_LOGIN` to a predetermined value ("readonly"). When set `HTTP_LOGIN` unconditionally, this works as expected, but I want `HTTP_LOGIN` conditionally set whenever `SSO_SOLUTION` is set to `none`.

```
SetEnv SSO_SOLUTION none
SetEnvIf SSO_SOLUTION ^none$ HTTP_LOGIN=readonly
```

This doesn't seem to work, but I understood from the [Apache documents](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#SetEnvIf) that it should. Am I misinterpreting the docs and/or am I misconfiguring things here?

`mod_setenvif` is configured in the configuration (but can I query that from the running webserver too, just to double check?). There are no unexpected errors in the log.

Platform: RHEL 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching from source resources on your problem I found an **excellent Env test matrix** done by [Turboflash](http://turboflash.wordpress.com/).

Here is the full test matrix post:
http://turboflash.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/

And the really interesting thing thing for you is on the result of A_2 environment variable which is empty.

On the final matrix he said **environment variable set by `Setenv` were not available from `SetenvIf`**. But this is not the case for environment variables set via `SetenvIf` (B_2).

So you should try to used `SetenvIf` instead of `Setenv` with an always matching rule like `Remote_Addr "^"` this way:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr "^" SSO_SOLUTION=none
SetEnvIf SSO_SOLUTION ^none$ HTTP_LOGIN=readonly
```

And also use SetenvIf on the other parts used on setting SSO_SOLUTION (and do not alter this env value with mod_rewrite, check the matrix).

Comment: That does the trick, yes. I did however use SERVER_SOFTWARE as I wasn't sure if REMOTE_ADDR would be set in the main Apache configuration (I didn't test REMOTE_ADDR either though).